# mount.nfs: Stale file handle error - cannot umount

Tags: mount, nfs, unmounting

Every time I try to mount a NFS share I get this:

```
>> mount -t nfs gitlab-replica-storage.blah.com:/export/registry-gitlab-prod-data-vol /mnt/test
mount.nfs: Stale file handle
```

The problem is that I cannot umount, as it says:

```
>> umount -f -l /mnt/test
umount: /mnt/test: not mounted
```

I tried checking if any process was using the mountpoint, but that is not the case.

Any other alternative to troubleshoot this?

As clarification:

- I can mount it in another machine.
- I cannot mount it in another mountpoint on the affected machine.

Comment: Are you positive the `/export/registry-gitlab-prod-data-vol` directory exists and has the correct permissions?

Comment: @Jaken551 Yes, it is accessible by someone else. In fact I can mount it in another machine.

Comment: Try to add `-v` to `mount -t` command. See `dmesg` and `/var/log/messages` also. Maybe addition info will be issued. Are you trying reboot your machine?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The error, ESTALE, was originally introduced to handle the situation
>   where a file handle, which NFS uses to uniquely identify a file on the
>   server, no longer refers to a valid file on the server.  This can
>   happen when the file is removed on the server, either by an
>   application on the server, some other client accessing the server, or
>   sometimes even by another mounted file system from the same client. 
>   The NFS server also returns this error when the file resides upon a
>   file system which is no longer exported.  Additionally, some NFS
>   servers even change the file handle when a file is renamed, although
>   this practice is discouraged.
>
> This error occurs even if a file or directory, with the same name, is
>   recreated on the server without the client being aware of it.  The
>   file handle refers to a specific instance of a file and deleting the
>   file and then recreating it creates a new instance of the file.
>
> The error, ESTALE, is usually seen when cached directory information
>   is used to convert a pathname to a dentry/inode pair. The information
>   is discovered to be out of date or stale when a subsequent operation
>   is sent to the NFS server.  This can easily happen in system calls
>   such as stat(2) when the pathname is converted a dentry/inode pair
>   using cached information, but then a subsequent GETATTR call to the
>   server discovers that the file handle is no longer valid.
>
> This error can also occur when a change is made on the server in
>   between looking up different components of the pathname to be looked
>   up or between a successful lookup and a subsequent operation.

Original link about ESTALE: [ESTALE LWN](https://lwn.net/Articles/272684/) .

I suggest to you check files and directories on NFS server or say to admin of NFS server to do this.

Maybe some old pagecache, inode, dentry cache entries are exists on NFS server. Please clean it:

```
# To free pagecache
echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

# To free dentries and inodes
echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

# To free pagecache, dentries and inodes
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Answer (score 28):

A `mount -t nfs` fails with `Stale file handle` if the server has some stale exports entries for that client.

Example scenario: this might happen when the server reboots without the client umounting the nfs volumes first. When the server is back and the client then umounts and tries to mount the nfs volume the server might respond with:

```
mount.nfs: Stale file handle
```

You can check for this via looking at `/proc/fs/nfs/exports` or `/proc/fs/nfsd/exports`. If there is entry for the client it might be a stale one.

You can fix this via explicitly un-exporting and re-exporting the relevant exports on the server. For example to do this with all exports:

```
# exportfs -ua
# cat /proc/fs/nfs/exports
# exportfs -a
```

After this the client's `mount -t nfs ...` should succeed.

Note that mount yielding `ESTALE` is quite different from some other system call (like open/readdir/unlink/chdir ...) returning `ESTALE`. It's export being stale vs. a file handle being stale. A stale file handle easily happens with NFS (e.g. a client has a file handle but the file got deleted on the server).

Comment: but how is it even usable when "A stale file handle easily happens with NFS " is a fact of life?

Comment: Just want to add that this worked for me when the server is running Manjaro Linux and the client is running Ubuntu. Furthermore, the conditions that led to this are that I moved a drive from one server to another, unmounting the device from the clients before the move, but one client ended up giving me the "stale file handle" error when I tried to mount the nfs share from the new server. Executing the commands in this answer fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I was also getting error "mount.nfs: Stale file handle", while mounting new volume.
This was happening since the older volume which was mounted got deleted.
After unmounting, the volume using,

```
umount /mnt
```

When I mounted again, it solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Find the stale mount entry on the NFS server:

```
showmount -a | grep ip_address_of_nfs_client
```

If you see lines related with the IP address of the NFS client and the share you are trying to mount, remove the stale entries from the rmtab:

```
vi /var/lib/nfs/rmtab
```

Reload the rpc.mountd so it sees the new rmtab:

```
killall rpc.mountd ; /usr/sbin/rpc.mountd
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the export is actually mounted:

```
# cat /proc/mounts | grep nfs
```

Stale file handle error means that the NFS server holds an old version of the files in his export path. An NFS server restart can sometimes help.
But with older OSs (RHEL/CentOS 6.9) it is sometimes better to revert to NFS3 instead of NFS4. In my experience older NFS4 clients have sometimes difficulties with the newer NFS4.1 servers. This is especially true for file locking.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to mount a NFS share hosted on TrueNAS on my Ubntu install and was getting this error.

What fixed it for me was restarting the NFS service on the TrueNAS server.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
umount -l /your-mount-path
or
umount -lf /your-mount-path
and
mount -a
```

Some docs using man

```
man umount:
    
       -f     Force   unmount
    
       -l     Lazy unmount. Detach the filesystem from the filesystem hierar-
              chy  now,  and cleanup all references to the filesystem as soon
              as it is not busy anymore.
```