# ls: cannot access pul: Stale file handle

Tags: ls

I'm trying to `cd` into directory `pul`, but I keep getting the error

```
ls: cannot access pul: Stale file handle
```

This is occurring on a remote work server that I am ssh'ing into, and I've never had issues before accessing this directory. Could someone advise on troubleshooting steps?

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/447581/117549

Comment: Perhaps more pertinent, since it talks about cd'ing to a directory that has disappeared: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20105260/what-does-stale-file-handle-in-linux-mean.